# Difference in Matlab contour and Desmos contour

Tags: matlab, graph

I've plotted a hyperbola on both Matlab and on Desmos.com using the same values and formulas.

Graph in Matlab

[image: Graph in Matlab]

Graph in Desmos.com

[image: Graph in Desmos.com]

They look similar and seem to have the same values, but the left hyperbola plotted in Matlab has a discontinuity and there seems to be something weird to the right in the graph. My code looks like this in Matlab:

```
function TDoACalculation()

syms x y deltaD D f;
s1x = 95; s1y = 0; s2x = 0; s2y = 0;

D = sqrt((s1y-s2y).^2+(s1x-s2x).^2);
deltaD = sqrt((95-x).^2-(0-y).^2)-sqrt((0-x).^2-(0-y).^2);
f = ((x.^2)/((deltaD.^2)/(4))-(y.^2)/(((D.^2)/(4))-((deltaD.^2)/(4)))) - 1
disp(f);

figure
fcontour(f, [-50 50  -50 50]);
end
```

Is there something wrong with how I've written the Matlab code to have caused this or is it the way I've done it in Desmos?

Comment: MATLABs plot is more accurate, the desmos plot cuts the fucntion in a different value (its a contour of the surface that you are plotting, not the surface), and desmos ignores the rightmost part, it doesnt expand the boundary enough.

Comment: I guess, your function is not exactly a hyperbola. Try to plot the surface -- `fsurf(f, [-30,30 -30,30])`. You will see that some spikes are there on the surface and that explains why there is a discontinuity in the contour plot.